# Unwanted margin issue in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have a weird problem in Internet Explorer 7 which shows heading with a lot of distance from the top. The problem does not exists in other browsers or newer versions of IE.

What should I do to make it right?

**Chrome Version:**
[image: Most of browsers show what exactly should show!]
**IE 7 Version:**
[image: IE puts some space above the title.]

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <header class="module-title">
        <h2 class="title">گزارش و مصاحبه</h2>
    </header>
    <section class="module-content">
        <ul class="sidebar-news">
            <li>
                <div class="image-holder">
                    <img src="img.jpg" alt="Test item">
                </div>
                <h3><a class="moduleItemTitle" href="#">Copy of مصاحبه با معاون صدا درباره راديو كتاب</a></h3>
                .
                .
                .

            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.module-title h2 { margin-top: 0; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; } 
.sidebar-news { list-style: none; margin: 0; }
.sidebar-news h3 { font-size: 20px; line-height: 26px; margin-top: 0; }
.sidebar-news .image-holder { width: 140px; float: right; margin-left: 10px; }
```

**Update 1:** I fixed it by giving `*margin: -20px;` to `.sidebar-news h3` but I don't like my solution! Why is this happening? Is there something adding that gap?

Comment: Did you [reset your css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) first?

Comment: Is not supporting IE7 an option?

Comment: @Seza yes, I'm using `Bootstrap` with reset option enabled and also I'm loading `Modernizr.js`

Comment: @DerekHenderson It's not an option, too many people are still using it and I have to support that in my code.

Comment: @faridv I don't think the verbiage, `too many people using it` is quite applicable. Seeing as how [http://theie7countdown.com/](http://theie7countdown.com/) has been tracking this for years, and it's market share is sub 1% worldwide. Not to mention the security risks involved with IE7 alone, I'd just simply sniff the UA and tell them to get a new browser or go home.

Comment: @faridv, that's a shame, because IE7 usage globally is down below 1%, closer to 0.5%.  Of course, if your unique site visitor statistics paint a different picture, that's understandable. But if not, I think you'll find you'll be doing an inordinate amount of work to support almost negligible numbers.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I know it's not pleasant to say that and I think you know that the IE is pain in the a** for all web developers including me. I have to add so much extra time to fix IE problems and I really don't like that. But what should I do when the employer is using IE7 himself and when I say I won't support IE7 he says *when I'm using it, there are too many peoples like me that are using it, so you have to make it look right for everyone*.

Comment: @faridv I can't offer any sage advice you probably don't already know, but I'd point out to your employer that IE7 has zero-day exploits which could leave his computer completely vulnerable to being overtaken and having all of his or her information readily available; not to mention any unsecured data it could accrue from the network. The implications of using IE7 in a work place are very negative, and coming from someone who's been in this field for quite some time, I would *urge* your employer to change from IE7.

Comment: @DerekHenderson It's not really good to know that about 4% of my visitors are using Internet Explorer 7!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply float property to achieve this in IE7.

```
.module-title h2 { margin-top: 0; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; } 
.sidebar-news { list-style: none; margin: 0; border:1px solid red; float:left; }
.sidebar-news .image-holder{ float:right;}
.sidebar-news h3 { font-size: 20px; line-height: 26px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; }
.sidebar-news .image-holder { width: 140px; float: right; margin-left: 10px; }
```

Comment: giving `float` will make it right in IE7 but other browsers are rendering the page differently becase of the not floated text after the image and title.

Comment: @faridv, don't use hacks!  If you have to support IE7, use IE conditional comments to load an IE7-specific stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

See #2 in this list:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/

Basically, I think the quickest fix should be to put `float: left;` on your "h3" element

Comment: I have to use right float on this but it makes the page worse in other browsers.

Comment: Older IEs have issues with its HasLayout property. Zoom:1, overflow:hidden and such might fix this.

Comment: @faridv, I understand that this may have a negative effect on other browsers.  In that case, apply the `float: left;` with with an asterisk in front as `*float: left;` which is an IE7-only CSS hack. This means that only IE7 will parse that line.  If you have to do this, then make sure you also leave a comment denoting that it is an IE7-only hack.  They are usually discouraged, but in this limited scenario I think it is an acceptable solution.

Comment: @JacobMcLock As I commented on 'samshah', I have to use `*float` but I'm looking for a solution to keep my css file validate-able.

Comment: @faridv, ok I see.  That is an unfortunate requirement in this circumstance.  Anything else to fix it is only a guess unless you can post a live example.  What negative consequence happens in other browsers when you do not use the '*'?  Or could you instead try `position: relative; top: 0;`?